# JTable to Excel using POI: how to position data at center of sheet?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm new to Java! I am able to export my JTable data to Excel using the snippet below. However the only concern I have is that the table is always printed at the very first column.

How can I go about positioning it at the center of the sheet?

```
Row row;
Cell cell = null;
for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
        cell = row.createCell(j);
        cell.setCellValue((String) model.getValueAt(i, j));
    }
}
```

Comment: What you expect to be the "center of the sheet" according to the columns? Sure, column `A` is always the leftmost column. But how much more to right will be the column `B` depends on the width of column `A` which is variable. So it is nearly impossible to center an Excel sheet only by moving it's content in other columns. The best practice is using [Page Setup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-page-margins-before-printing-a-worksheet-353f52fc-0d2c-4958-9166-99fbd22b963a) to do this.